# List - > details flow. Best practices Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-cursoradapter

I was wondering, what are the best practices or preferred way to handle with list and details flow in Android.

Example:

a) I have fragment A with a list of items.

b) When user select an item, I will show item details in another screen (Activity or fragment, for this question purpose this doesn't matter).

All my data are stored into database, using Content Provider.

Question:

Should I get just an item id in fragment A, pass as extra to screen B and select entire data using a cursor loader in screen B

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Launch intent with id param.
}
```

Or select entire data in fragment A and pass as extra to screen B?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO get selected item.
    Parking parking = (Parking) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    // Launch intent with parking as extra.
}
```

Best practices?

Comment: *All my data are stored into database, using Content Provider.* and then `(Parking) parent.getAdapter()` .... why on hell you are using `Arraydapter<T>` instead `CursorAdapter`? ... best practices is, if you are using CP, is to use CP's uris like `content://my.cp.auth/parkings/1`

Comment: I'm not using Arraydapter<T>. Super implementation of CursorAdapter returns a cursor positioned at specified position.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vitorvigano/739cdd2f102b13e2836f

Comment: Then your onItemClick implementation will throw classcastexception

Comment: No, check gist example.

Comment: Aha ok... Just don't do this... If you need a model give a parking class static method fromCursor... SimpleCursorAdaper is good enough eventually with ViewBinder...  In your case you will end with writing a model specific cursorloader for all models

Comment: Hm, ok. I'll try. But what about question best practices? Should I build this model and pass as extra to screen B, or pass just selected id and fetch database again in screen B?

Comment: As I wrote pass Uri which used with CP will return the right row

Comment: I guess that I got it. I will pass selected id, append with uri path, and get details, right?

Comment: yes, normally if you implement CP you have `content://my.cp.auth/parkings` for dir (for example all rows from parkings table) and `content://my.cp.auth/parkings/#` which returns cursor with only one row (fx. `content://my.cp.auth/parkings/1` should returns the row from parkings table with id = 1) ... now it will be easy to build item uri with  `ContentUris.withAppendedId(ParkingContract.CONTENT_URI, id)` and pass it to details Activity/Fragment ... there is also some added value ... you can even use such uri in html page :) and if you setup intent-filter properly it should open detailsactivity